# How to extract out a pattern from data in two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to extract out cases where the Power_2 column occurred after Power_1 occurred.

I have a dataframe (similar to the one below), which has data on two electrical loads, `Power_1` and `Power_2`, and I am trying to understand how often `Power_2` was turned on after `Power_1` was turned on.  My actual data contains many more rows than the data frame below, but I wanted to illustrate what my data looked like.

Basically, I am trying to understand if there is a pattern, or how to visualize when `Power_2` was turned on after `Power_1`.

My hypothesis I want to test is that, If `Power_2` is turned on after `Power_1`, then that means there is a certain pattern.  And if `Power 2` wasn't turned on after `Power_1`, then that means the user is doing something different.

```
TimeStamp   Power_1   Power_2
6:00:00    0            0
6:00:01    0            0
6:00:02    0.538906412  0
6:00:03    0.230903467  0
6:00:04    0            0.002241299
6:00:05    0            0.971594583
6:00:06    0            0
6:00:07    0            0
6:00:08    0            0
6:00:09    0.898974742  0
6:00:10    0.266201046  0
6:00:11    0            0.752396849
6:00:12    0            0.662316668
6:00:13    0            0.721062372
6:00:14    0            0    
6:00:15    0            0.344280835
6:00:16    0.149564236  0
6:00:17    0.5211515    0
6:00:18    0.957654133  0
6:00:19    0            0
6:00:20    0            0
```

Comment: Does 0 mean its not on?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand the conditions are you looking for when power_2 becomes positive after being `0` if the previous row in power_1 was also positive?

Comment: More specifically, if power_1 and power_2 are 0 does that mean everything is off.  In your example is 1 on before 2 at :02-:05 and :09-:13 but 2 on before 1 at :14-:18?

Comment: For example, I am trying to see if one switch is typically hit after another.  So, if this data is for a bathroom, is the bathroom light switched on (Power_1) before the switch for the mirror light is switched off (Power_2).  There will likely be cases where the bathroom isn't switched on but the mirror light is, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I'd map your data to a new structure: Timestamp + PowerSource where PowerSource can either be 0, 1 or 2.

```
TimeStamp   PowerSource
6:00:00    0
6:00:01    0
6:00:02    1
6:00:03    1
6:00:04    2
6:00:05    2
6:00:06    0
6:00:07    0
6:00:08    0
6:00:09    1
6:00:10    1
6:00:11    2
6:00:12    2
6:00:13    2
6:00:14    0
6:00:15    2
6:00:16    1
6:00:17    1
6:00:18    1
6:00:19    0
6:00:20    0
```

Then loop over your new structure checking for changes in power source only caring about 1 and 2.

```
var array = [all of your data];
var lastPowerSource = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var value = array[i];
  var time = value.timeStamp;
  var powerSource = value.powerSource;
  if (lastPowerSource != 0) {
    if (powerSource != lastPowerSource) {
      console.log("Power source changed from " + lastPowerSource + " to " + powerSource + " at " + time);      
    }
  }
  lastPowerSource = powerSource;
}
```

This would give you something like:

```
Power source changed from 1 to 2 at 6:00:04
Power source changed from 1 to 2 at 6:00:11
Power source changed from 2 to 1 at 6:00:16
```

Obviously this is just pseudocode (actually javascript) and you could add a specific check for when lastPowerSource is 2 and powerSource is 1 if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

i think following code will give you the pattern if column 1 is greater than zero and column 2 is greater zero:

```
a['pattern']=(a['Power_1']>0) & (a['Power_2']>0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, still I assumed that when power is greater than 0, the power is on. Also I believe that the df is always ordered by TimeStamp column

```
import pandas as pd

Power1=False
Power2=False
PreviousPower='None'
grpcontPowerone=[]
grpcontPowertwo=[]
grpPoweronetotwo=[]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Power_1']>0 and PreviousPower=='Power_1':
        grpcontPowerone.extend([index-1,index])
    elif row['Power_2']>0 and PreviousPower=='Power_2':
        grpcontPowertwo.extend([index-1,index])
    elif row['Power_2']>0 and PreviousPower=='Power_1':
        grpPoweronetotwo.extend([index-1,index])

    if row['Power_1']>0:
        PreviousPower='Power_1'
    elif row['Power_2']>0:
        PreviousPower='Power_2'
    else:
        PreviousPower='None'

print "When power 1 is contiously turned on"
print df.iloc[list(set(grpcontPowerone))].sort_values('TimeStamp')

print "When power 2 is contiously turned on"
print df.iloc[list(set(grpcontPowertwo))].sort_values('TimeStamp')  

print "Power is switched from one to two"
print df.iloc[list(set(grpPoweronetotwo))].sort_values('TimeStamp')
```

output

```
When power 1 is contiously turned on
   TimeStamp   Power_1  Power_2
2    6:00:02  0.538906      0.0
3    6:00:03  0.230903      0.0
9    6:00:09  0.898975      0.0
10   6:00:10  0.266201      0.0
16   6:00:16  0.149564      0.0
17   6:00:17  0.521151      0.0
18   6:00:18  0.957654      0.0
When power 2 is contiously turned on
   TimeStamp  Power_1   Power_2
4    6:00:04      0.0  0.002241
5    6:00:05      0.0  0.971595
11   6:00:11      0.0  0.752397
12   6:00:12      0.0  0.662317
13   6:00:13      0.0  0.721062
Power is switched from one to two
   TimeStamp   Power_1   Power_2
3    6:00:03  0.230903  0.000000
4    6:00:04  0.000000  0.002241
10   6:00:10  0.266201  0.000000
11   6:00:11  0.000000  0.752397
```